# What is the purpose of using tmpsfs over using the writable layer of docker containers?

Tags: docker

On can bind a tmpfs volume to a docker container, but what is its use over just writing to the writable layer ? (say I write into /tmp/ without mounting anything)

The docs says (https://docs.docker.com/storage/tmpfs/):

> This is useful to temporarily store sensitive files that you don’t
> want to persist in either the host or the container writable layer

But both are temporary, so wouldn't you be fine with using the writable layer ?

Comment: if use `docker commit` to build docker images, then the `/tmp` files may accidently be persistent?

Answer (score 0):

A container's writable layer is usually stored in the container's filesystem, separate from the read-only image layers. When changes are made within a running container, they are written to this writable layer. If you commit those changes to a new image, the writable layer becomes part of the new image, allowing persistence of modifications. This way, subsequent containers based on the new image will have those changes.

Comment: So it's only useful in the purpose of image creation ?

Comment: As I see it, it adds a bit of extra security.